# UITableView show some row

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

I have a problem with `UITableView` in `UIViewController`.My table shows some row that I don't know why. It should be show all of row.

[image: simulator]
[image: Prototype]

```
class TableViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {
    let cellIdentifier = "testCell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return 20
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.lableName.text = "Hello man"

    return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: is your cell height is different than the default cell height?

Comment: You don't have configured data in data source method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` then how can tableview shows data!

Comment: you have entered number of rows are 20 so table view create 20 rows

Comment: Your question is not clear. You need to tell us more about what you are expecting. Are you expecting to see 20 rows, each containing "Hollo man"?

Comment: I think your constraint are not configure properly on your label. so some times it shows and some time it's out of view.So check your constraint.

Comment: yes, I want to see "Hello man" in 20 row

Comment: please put color in cell background. So exactly see the main problem either you haven't set proper constraints of cell or table view doesn't create 20 rows.

Answer (score 1):

if you want hello man in 20 row.(All row)in cell for row at index path method add this line

cell.labelname.text = "Hello Man"

Comment: I try to add 
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        
        cell.lableName.text = "Hello!!"

but It shows like previous

Comment: have you define cell class?@Telember

Comment: yes, I created a class for UITableViewCell and add a label. when I changed a text of the label  that my row change a word  but it shows some row same previous

Answer (score 0):

Please check your tableview delegate and datasource.
BTW,set right constraints.